# Why session should be a param when you write a query function?

Tags: database, libraries, patterns-and-practices, functions

I read a lot of examples where I read code like this:

```
def get_user_by_id(session, id)
...
```

and the function that calls that function needs to create or get the DB session a pass to the function.

the question is why the general design is doing that instead of creating or getting sessions inside the function?

Thanks.

Comment: What is a `session` in this context? From your code, I'm guessing it _might_  be something Pythonic, but even so you need to tell us which DB access library you're using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why let people pass in a `session` rather than build it for them?

So that the function is also useful in contexts where `session` already exists.

If it doesn’t they can always build it and pass it.

Design it the other way around and they’re stuck always making a new one. Even when they don’t need it.

That isn't to say that it wouldn't be nice to also have this:

```
def get_user_by_id(id)
```

Which would make the `session` for you. It's just really nice to also have the other which lets you reuse an existing `session`. As a plus you can design this one so it uses the other and avoid duplicate code.

If you want to do more research on externalizing variables like this it goes by the names: parameterize, reference passing, and dependency injection.

Why so many names? Because a good idea is never allowed to only have one simple name.

Comment: Thanks, I will read more about that, but anyway I have another question about this, for example, if you are developing an API, and in each endpoint, you need to create a new connection, in this case the same if you create in the controller or in the model that will be the function, so, in this case, doesn't matter, or is a better choice keep dependency injection too?.

Comment: @Tlaloc-ES I've reread your comment 3 times now and I can't quite follow it. You're mentioning an API, controller, a model, and a need to create a new connection. But I can't see what the context is that would be relevant to choosing whether to parameterize. Little help?

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume "*creating or getting sessions inside the function*" is the way at start.

For any real world API, `get_user_by_id` is not going to be the only method is it?

There are likely to exist similar methods: `get_posts_by_user(post_id)`, `get_comments_for_post(user_id)`, `like_post(post_id)` and so on.

Would it make sense to duplicate session creation code everywhere ?

Obviously not. Lets suppose we extract the common logic regarding creation or retrieval of a, DB or Authentication, session in `session_provider.get_session()`.

How are all the API methods going to get `session_provider` in the first place ?

Well, it can be saved in globally accessible state or even can be a singleton. It is general consensus that both [global state](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/148108/65405) and [singletons](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/40373/65405) are best avoided.

The remaining option is to **pass** the `session_provider` from outside (by whomever that wants to call the API methods.) Also known as *providing dependencies externally*.

Lets suppose the `session_provider` is passed to the constructor  of API class having all these methods:

```
class api {
  constructor(session_provider){...}

  get_user_by_id(user_id){
    session = this.session_provider.get_session();
    ...
  }
}
```

So far so great. Now let's focus how other code uses the API. Suppose a request handling function:

```
 handle_get_user_request(http_request){

    provider = new session_provider();

    api = new api(provider);

    user_id = http_request.get_param('id');

    return api.get_user_by_id(user_id);
 }
```

Are not we doing the same mistake again ? Creating the dependencies of a function inside it!

Considering we fully embrace the "*providing dependencies externally*" concept, we would have code where, the things required to compute something, are **passed** to the function doing the computation:

```
 handle_get_user_request(http_request, api, session){
    user_id = http_request.get_param('id');
    return api.get_user_by_id(session, user_id);
 }
```

Here we are, with `get_user_by_id(session, user_id)` version of the function. Welcome to [Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/130794).