# When to use a Singleton and when to use a static class

Tags: java, object-oriented, class, singleton, static-methods

I've searched about this here and on StackOverflow and found some differences between the two.

But I'm still not sure *in what cases one would prefer a Singleton, and in what cases one would choose to use a static class*.

(In languages which don't support 'static classes', like Java, I'm obviously referring to classes containing only static methods and fields).

Please give me concrete examples of cases where you would pick each one, and explain why.

Comment: in most cases it should be neither

Comment: this has been asked and answered many times here and at SO, see eg: [When is Singleton appropriate?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/252/when-is-singleton-appropriate) and [What is the difference between all-static-methods and applying a singleton pattern?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/34485/what-is-the-difference-between-all-static-methods-and-applying-a-singleton-patte) (comments in the latter question point to duplicates at SO)

Comment: What do you need a static class for? They have their uses, so it'll be helpful to know before giving any kind of advice.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A case where a static class might be a good idea is when you want to collect related pieces of functionality, but you don't need to have any internal state in any object. An example could be the Math class in Java. It contains a whole bunch of related functions that are accessed outside the context of any specific object instance. I've done similar things where a set of common utility functions that are used in multiple places in an application are grouped together into a single utility class.

A singleton is used when you *do* want an actual object (with its own internal state and everything), and you want to limit your system to exactly *one* instance of that object. This might be useful if you have some kind of shared resource, such as a database, an in-memory cache, or maybe some specialized piece of hardware like a robotic arm. Many parts of your program might want to use this resource and you might want to have all access to the resource go through a single point. A singleton isn't always the *only* way to handle these situations, but it's one of the few places I think a singleton *might* be a good choice.

Comment: So basically a Singleton is used when I want to ensure all access to some object goes through a specific point, and ensure there's only one of these - like a database?

Comment: If so, question: A static class can also have internal state that can be manipulated and used, just like an object, right?

Comment: [Don't use Singleton](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/40610/116461). @Prog: Yes, but it shouldn't have any.

Comment: @Doval Why shouldn't it?

Comment: @Prog Because you're just using global variables in disguise. All parts of your application that make any calls to the static class are now *invisibly* **dependent** on each other, and any parts of your application that are dependent on *those* parts are now indirectly dependent as well, and so on. Mutable state is already a bad idea if you can avoid it. Global mutable state is just a bad idea.

Comment: @Prog - that's a different question ("Why should a static class have no state?").  Please ask it separately, not in the comments here.

Comment: But aren't singletons global variables in disguise too? The "get instance" function call simply returns a reference to the huge global object containing all the state right? It seems like it's even worse: god object + global state.

Comment: @user54609 Yes. That's why they're a bad idea too, as explained in the answer I linked to.

Comment: @Doval Please consider a 'database object'. This object holds data used by several objects in the app. The data in this object is updated from time to time. This object is implemented as a Singleton, so it can be accessed easily by any object that needs this data. Say objects A, B and C needs this data from time to time, so they access the Singleton object. You said that it makes them all *invisibly dependent on each other* - how come? Please explain this.

Comment: @Prog just because there's only one database it doesn't mean you want to enwrap database access in a singleton, for example because you can't mock a singleton and thus inject a "dummy" database into a unit test, for example. Okay, you CAN mock a singleton, but this can require a bit of voodoo (depending on your language of choice) and isn't very convenient.

Comment: @Prog As pointed out by Scott, you should ask a new question for that one. We've strayed too far off course from this one.

Answer (score 14):

- Avoid the Gang of Four Singleton pattern, for reasons cited in the other answers. Mainly it is an anti-pattern based on difficulties it creates for testing.
- Factory and Dependency Injection made Singleton obsolete. The best answer is to use a Factory that decides whether to instantiate one instance, or many, of a given class. That way, the class and its clients aren't responsible for its singleton status -- that becomes a transparent concern managed by the Factory.
- Dependency injection frameworks like Spring do that for you out of the box (e.g. Spring beans are singletons unless you specify otherwise).
- Purely static classes are problematic for both testing and using OO concepts. I've seen teams with an irresistible urge to make *everything* static and final, and the question becomes, why aren't they just writing C code?
- If your static class has side effects, then it should not be static. That means, if it's managing shared state, or if it's changing the state of parameters, then it should be a regular class where the Factory hands out a single shared instance. A purely static class that manages shared state becomes a really hard problem for testing.
- A purely static class also creates hard, compile-time dependencies on *that particular class*, which really compromises the extend-ability and test-ability of your code. Seems like you'd want to reserve that for something eternal and unchanging, with no side effects, like math formulas.

So the answer is, don't write classes as singletons, but rather move that decision into your Factory. And in an OO language, static classes miss some of the most important design aspects of the language and complicate testing. Again, you can use worker classes with specific semantics to bundle those up and have them generated by your Factory.

Comment: +1 for your second bullet point. Factories can be a good abstraction of object construction, to include caching instances when appropriate. It also adds flexibility to change the instance if needed, e.g. for injecting a mock test class.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Thing is, in order for me to be able to create instances of that class from anywhere in the program, I need the Factory to be global. Calls for a Singleton..?

Comment: If you have to do something bad, then concentrating it in one place is a good mitigating factor. ;) But in this case, there are a couple of strategies you can use: 1) have your application framework *inject* a common type-specific factory into your classes, 2) use the Prototype pattern, in which an instance of an object turns into a kind of factory from which other instances are cloned. Essentially, you already have a global context -- the running application -- and that's what should be responsible for building & handing things out.

Answer (score 0):

Singletons objects made so there can only be 1 instance at any given time and can be used application wide.

Objects that handle stuff like connection pools are a good candidate to be Singletons;

- You only want 1 instance in the entire application
- you must be able to access it from different parts of the application
- the data it holds has to be persisted even when no other objects are currently pointing to it (handy when you want to reuse objects that are expensive to initialize).

A class filled with only static methods is not something that's usually meant to be initialized like an object. It's more like a wrapper for the static methods in it.

An example of this that I use frequently is a utility class with methods that do repetitive tasks that take parameters, does a calculation with them/formats them/etc. and then returns the result, without using any external (or at least no non-static) fields or methods.
I never initialize a utility class, I just use the static methods in it for all repetitive methods.

This is just how I tend to use Singletons and static (method filled) classes, not sure if it confirms to any "official" standards...

Comment: FrustratedWithFormsDesig already gave a better answer in the time I took to type my answer...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If you have an entity that needs to be accessible from anywhere in your application and only one instance of it at a time, like a database, why not implement it as a static class? Static classes can also hold internal state and have public methods to access and manipulate it. Why not simply implement a static class?

Comment: For me personaly it's the convenience of only having to make the instance object and getInstance() method static. This avoids a lot of "can't call non-static method" kind of errors. Other than that I can't really come up with a valid reason.

Comment: I was confused for a moment why Rob gave two answers, but then I realized